# Interrupted mouseenter causes looping click

Tags: jquery

I have some *small divs* that, when clicked, show a *bigger div* that overlays everything - kind'a like a lightbox. In order to hide the *big div*, I click it (there's no "close this" link).

Here's the click code:

```
// First click - draw in
$('.compositos_DBitem').on('click', function(){
    // Some stuff going on here...
                function(){
                    // Animate the lightbox elements
                    $('.compositos_DBitem_lightbox', this).fadeIn(500);
                    $('.compositos_lightboxBackground').fadeIn(500);
                    // Second click - draw back
                    $(this).on('click', function(){
                        $('.compositos_DBitem_lightbox', this).fadeOut(500);
                        $('.compositos_lightboxBackground').fadeOut(500);
                    });
                });
});
```

The **.compositos_lightboxBackground** is the background overlaying div and the **.compositos_DBitem_lightbox** are the *big divs*.

The problem is that, after clicking the *big div* (when it's showing), it fades out and back in - if you don't leave de *big div's* area. If I click it and take the mouse out fast, it then works.

What's wrong?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5nAWP/)

Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better suited using `fadeToggle`, because as of right now, you are repeatedly binding additional functions to the `click` event.

```
// First click - draw in
$('.compositos_DBitem').on('click', function(){
    // Some stuff going on here...
                function(){
                    // Animate the lightbox elements
                    $('.compositos_DBitem_lightbox', this).fadeToggle(500);
                    $('.compositos_lightboxBackground').fadeToggle(500);
                });
});
```

`fadeToggle` does exactly what you were looking to do with your previous code, but allows you to only bind to the `click` event once.

Previously, your code would bind the fade out to the click event, and it would execute immediately when clicked. So would the other function (the animation) that you had previously bound to the click event. The animation would then execute it's callback when it would finish...which showed the 'lightbox' divs again.